# Jenkins and JaCoCo with sbt

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a project in Jenkins that I want to create a JaCoCo code coverage report.
If I run `jacoco:test` then `jacoco:report` locally it creates the correct files (.exec, .classes and sources) in `myproject/target/scala-2.9.1/jacoco` so it works.

However when building on jenkins this only creates the classes directory meaning it picks up the code but not the test that cover it so I get 0% code coverage.

Has anyone got jacoco working with sbt in this way?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this same issue when trying to start a new Scala project. After trying a number of path configurations, I was able to figure a solution.

The default value for Path to class directories is `**/classes`. I suspect the issue is that the pattern allows for matching `target/scala-X.XX/classes/` and `target/scala-X.XX/jacoco/classes/`.

Changing the class directory path to `target/*/classes` allowed the Jenkins plug-in to start reporting the correct coverage information.

Comment: Astonishing! Thanks to this post I found I needed to use `**/target/*/classes`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please tell in detail for which property we need to set "target/*/classes" ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give much information about your Jenkins job configuration, so I'm making some assumptions, but you can add/execute multiple build steps in a Jenkins job.  Build steps run things like run Maven or run any arbitrary script.

The first build step can be a Maven build step that executes "jacoco:test jacoco:report" to run Jacoco and then the second build step can be whatever else you run that is looking for the jacoco.exec file.